# How to add missing referrer header to Cordova IOS App

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap

I am using Cordova to build an iOS App. I use the [Ionic engine](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview) meaning that the app is served from a webserver running on the device.

My `window.location.origin` is "ionic://my-app.com".

A third party API (that I need to use in order to fetch an address suggestion based on what the user types) rejects my HTTP requests because the `referrer` header is missing in the request.

It's not possible to programmatically add a referrer from the JS layer and these did not work:

- `<meta name="referrer" content="origin">`
- `<meta name="referrer" content="always">`

I suspect that the issue is that the API is using `https` and my iOS App is using a custom scheme (the default one is `ionic://` and cannot be changed to https). For this reason the referrer header is not added by the WebView.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: **A 50 bounty will be given to anyone that helps solve this.**

Comment: Is it only that one API that restricts your access because of a missing referrer? You may not be desperate enough at this point, but routing your request through a server that you control to forward the request will work.

Comment: Yep, that's my last resort. It's the only API that currently restrics access because of the missing referrer. :(

Comment: If you control the third party API, you could send custom headers.

Comment: I don't control the third party API

Answer (score 1):

I'd try following the CORS workaround for native apps that uses the HTTP plugin from ionic. See here for more details:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors#1-native-only-apps-ios-android-

Comment: We are using Cordova, not Ionic. We use the cordova-plugin-ionic-webview plugin in order to use the Ionic engine and gain performance.

Comment: You don't need to use Ionic to use that plugin. It's a cordova plugin, you can find it here https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the webview package cordova-plugin-inappbrowser you can integrate this Pull Request in your code and you will be able to set a custom header with a custom value: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/363

I have done it and it works.